# Granting Permissions to NETWORK SERVICE to access a file location and Registry

Tags: c#, registry, file-permissions

I am running a scheduled task in the context of NETWORK Service account. I need to do some registry changes as well as access a location while running this task. How can I check if there is permission? If no permission I need to grant permission. This is done from a console application which is run as a part of the installation process (Custom action). The application is written in c#.

Comment: You really want to grant this kind of highly privileged access to the NETWORK SERVICE account??? Are you really sure that you want to allow **all processes** that run under NETWORK SERVICE to have this kind of access to the runnings of your machine (registry)? Sounds like madness to me. I'd consider making a specific service account for your process that isn't shared with other processes.

Comment: This scheduled task was earlier run using administrator account. Now the requirement is to run it using NETWORK SERVICE account. The registry access will be given to a specific folder only. @spender

Comment: So, unless you need to do this programmatically, I think this would be better to ask at serverfault.com

Comment: Did you ever figure this out. I'd hate to do impersonation just to be able to call some powershell within the network service context.